# Leaflet do not display points of a particular color from a layerGroup

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using leaflet to draw path associated to vehicles. Each vehicle path is composed of a layerGroup to make it possible to have different color in the path (as color depends on temperature). The data is received from a web socket in the following format (as displayed by the debug console of chromium):

```
Object {color: "#cc0099", legende: "<someHtmlCode.TheSameForEveryPieceOfData>", data: {lat: 48.77905, lon: -3.44891}, c2a_id: "vehicle_1"}
```

My problem is that for certain values of color (different shades of blue) the path is not drawn on the map but for the others it properly work. In the case I change the zoom level then everything is displayed (every color I'm using).

You can see that some blue has appeared on the second image (over previous paths), which should have been drown without the need of changing zoom level.

My code for adding the data to the layer.

```
var idAllLayers;
if (_data != null && _data['data'] != null) {
    current_lon = _data['data']['lon'];
    current_lat = _data['data']['lat'];

    // checking if there is already a layer associated to the vehicle _id_
    if (!(this.layer_group_real_time.hasLayer(id))) {
        var multi_polyline = L.layerGroup([]);  //create a layer for this vehicle
        multi_polyline._leaflet_id = id;
        //add a sublayer to this one (for a sub path to have different colors)
        multi_polyline.addLayer(this.newLayer(id, _data['color']));
        this.layer_group_real_time.addLayer(multi_polyline);
    }

    // get the differents layers of the layerGroup for the vehicle _id_
    idAllLayers = this.layer_group_real_time.getLayer(id).getLayers();
    currentLayerLatLng = idAllLayers[idAllLayers.length-1].getLatLngs();
    if (current_lat != null && current_lon != null) {
        // if previous elements have been stored
        if (this.previousDataPoints[id] != null && this.previousColor[id] != null) {
            oldDataPoint = this.previousDataPoints[id]['data'];
            delta = this.measure(current_lat, current_lon, oldDataPoint['lat'], oldDataPoint['lon']);
            if (delta > MAX_DIST || _data['color'] != this.previousColor[id]) { 
                if (delta < MAX_DIST){  // case where color has changed but we still need to add the point to the previous subpath
                    currentLayerLatLng.push(L.latLng(current_lat, current_lon));
                }                                     
                this.layer_group_real_time.getLayer(id).addLayer(this.newLayer(id, _data['color']));
                idAllLayers = this.layer_group_real_time.getLayer(id).getLayers();
                currentLayerLatLng = idAllLayers[idAllLayers.length - 1].getLatLngs();
             }
         }
         currentLayerLatLng.push(L.latLng(current_lat, current_lon));
         idAllLayers[idAllLayers.length - 1].setLatLngs(currentLayerLatLng);  // setting up the new coords
         this.previousDataPoints[id] = _data;
         this.previousColor[id] = _data['color'];
     }
 }

newLayer: function (_id, _color) {
        var nl = L.polyline([],
            {
                color: _color,
                opacity: 0.7,
                stroke: true,
                weight: 6,
                vehicle_id: _id
            });
        nl.on('click', this.traceOnClick);
        return nl;
    },
```

---

[EDIT]

Here is a "minimal, complete and verifiable example" (at least I hope it is) I've uploaded on [Github](https://github.com/SamHCadman/testLeafletColor). It contains a map where are displayed some path. On load displayed path should be green and pink but if you change zoom level blue path should appear. I've integrated @Jieter and @snkashis suggestions but the problem is still here.

Comment: You example is a bit hard to read, but I noticed you assign `_leaflet_id`s. That not something you're supposed to do, it might work, but might also introduce some hard to track errors. Do you possibly have id-collisions?

Comment: I've done that to easily find the layerGroup associated to one vehicle (the `multi_polyline` I create for a vehicle if it does not already exist). It's done for each vehicles layer but not at the sublayer level (the ones I add to the `multi_polyline`).
 I do not think I've id-collisions, I've no error about something like that and no point is added to the wrong path. I must admit I have no idea on how to be sure about that.
However I'll try to change the way I handle the different layers of each vehicle, without assigning `_leaflet_id`

Comment: Leaflet keeps layers in an object with the `_leaflet_id`s as keys. If you have disappearing layers, I suspect something gets overwritten because of the id's not being unique anymore.

Comment: I've changed my code so `_leaflet_i`d is no more directly edited. I use some associative array to easily find back the `layerGroup` associated to my vehicle. Unfortunately nothing has changed: the 'blue' sub layers are still not displayed when a point is added and only appear when changing zoom level. The disturbing point is that problems happen only when adding a point to a 'blue' segment of my path.

Comment: It would be easier to debug if we could look at a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It took me some time but I've updated my question with a GitHub link to example which should comply to what you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've come to the idea to change the type of the vehicle layer from `L.layerGroup` to `L.geoJson`. And it worked! Even if I don't know why.

I've updated the [Git repository](https://github.com/SamHCadman/testLeafletColor) with my solution.

---

(As previously said in comments I've also stoped doing `multi_polyline._leaflet_id = id;` and now use `L.Util.setOptions(vehicleLayer, {vehicle_id: id});`. I've renamed multi_polyline to vehicleLayer by the way.)

Comment: I was a bit slow in transforming your solution to something that works (stopped working on it since noting that you got it to work), some notes:

Comment: `L.LatLng` has a distanceTo method which does what your `measure` function does. Using complete latlng objects reduces the clutter in your code a bit because you need 2x less variables now.

Comment: Your example was not exactly minimal with 18k of JS code, you could have shown the problem with say 10 segments.

Comment: I've replace my ` measure` function by `distanceTo`. It works perfectly and the code is easier to read. I'll keep in mind your second advice for my next posts. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I still see `multi_polyline._leaflet_id = id;` in your example..why are you not using `L.Util.setOptions` to mark your own internal identifiers(vehicle id, etc)?

Comment: When I got my hand on this code it was done this way and I did not know about L.Util.setOptions. I've changed my code to use it but the problem is still here. I've updated my post with an example on GitHub.

Comment: And is there a specific reason why you cannot use a prebuilt plugin for this functionality like https://iosphere.github.io/Leaflet.hotline/demo/ instead of creating another implementation?

Comment: I did not know about the existence of this plugin. I've gave it a try. It does pretty nice things but it seems a bit heavy for me (map/browser becomes really slow after a few minutes displaying real time data) and it is also source of some problems with the map control (drag the map for example).